# count duplicates with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to count duplicates of files with PowerShell. My files have a special separator ('#') and I can only compare the part before the separator.

```
Mode        LastWriteTime   Length Name
----        -------------   ------ ----
-a----   23.09.2016 09:44        0 AnotherDuplicateOffer_#1265473v1.DOCX
-a----   23.09.2016 09:44        0 AnotherDuplicateOffer_#89798798546v1.DOCX
-a----   23.09.2016 09:44        0 AnotherDuplicateOffer_#98769876v1.DOCX
-a----   23.09.2016 09:44        0 DuplicateOffer_#1254798v1.DOCX
-a----   23.09.2016 09:44        0 DuplicateOffer_#34987094587v1.DOCX
-a----   23.09.2016 09:44        0 DuplicateOffer_#4986598v1.DOCX
-a----   23.09.2016 09:44        0 DuplicateOffer_#567809v1.DOCX
-a----   23.09.2016 09:44        0 WordFilesAlthoug_#89798798546v1.DOCX
```

The part after the separator is a unique ID and at least I want to rename the files by removing this ID. So the new filename should be something like 'string (x).docx' and the 'x' should a counter for the duplicates.

I'm stuck by counting the duplicates:

```
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer})) {
    $file.Name
    $file.Name.IndexOf("#")
    $file.Name.Substring(0, ($file.Name.IndexOf("#")))
    (dir *.* | group -Property Name | Where {($_.Name.Substring(0,($_.Name.IndexOf("#")))) -match ($_.Name.Substring(0,($_.Name.IndexOf("#"))))}).Count
}
```

I get the right index of '#' with `$file.Name.IndexOf("#")` and also the string of `$file.Name.Substring(0,($file.Name.IndexOf("#")))` is right. But when I use the same in the pipe I get exceptions in `Substring` because of the second part - this must be greater than 0 and it appears to be 0 or less.

For better understanding: `$_` is the same as `$file` - it is the actual pointer in the pipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply group the files by the first part of their name and select those groups that have more than one element.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse |
    Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
    Group-Object { ($_.Name -split '#')[0] } |
    Where-Object { $_.Count -ge 2 }
```

Rename the files by processing each group separately:

```
... | ForEach-Object {
    $i = 0
    $_.Group | ForEach-Object {
        $newname = $_.Name -replace '#\d+v\d+', "($i)"
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newname
        $i++
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks that works either. Anyway, i got my Probelm solved by myself. see update above

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got it working. The point was to give `dir` the right path. I didn't do this in the first time, because i thought this i given by my pointer `$file` but it is not. So giving the the right path is done with Parameter `-Path` and `$file.Directory`. This way `dir` gets the right path where the actuall `$file` is into.

`(dir -Path $file.Directory *.* | group -Property Name | Where{($_.Name.Substring(0,($_.Name.IndexOf("#")))) -match ($_.Name.Substring(0,($_.Name.IndexOf("#"))))}).Count`